# ajax/ssl/X-Forwarded-For

Tags: ajax, ssl

Ok, I'm using pen for load balancing.  My apache servers see the remote IP as the IP of the load balancer.  I need the apache server to be able to see the IP address of the client for various reasons.  I can use X-Forwarded-For to get that out of a non-encrypted page, but it's not part of an SSL page...

So, not knowing Ajax, I'm wondering.  Could I use ajax to pull the X-Forwarded-For out of a non encrypted page, and set it as a variable on the client side? I know it's possible, I'm just wondering if anyone has done this, and does this cause a security error in the browser.

I thought that I could redirect them to a non-ssl page, then put the IP in a cookie, then back to the SSL page, but I think that's hokey too.

Anyway other way to get the ip to the script will work too. I tried http://stderr.net/apache/rpaf/, but it's not aware of the IP either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX is limited by same-origin policy, and different protocols are considered different origins, so you wouldn't be able to make HTTP AJAX request from HTTPS page.

Attempt to do it via other means could cause browsers warn about mixed secure and insecure content.

Putting IP in a cookie on HTTP page (ideally signed or stored in server-side session referenced by the cookie) would work, but it will not be as secure as reading actual IP of SSL session (since attacker could manipulate HTTP cookies, and you can't set a HTTPS-only cookie).

Another solution to this is to end SSL at the load balancer and forward it as HTTP traffic to Apache.

Yet another approach would be to use lower-level load balancing — NAT — that preserves source address.